# StackOverflowException is caused by a default mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stack-overflow, defaultview

I created a simple create view for a model by mvc's automated way to show to a coleague.
Now, although i do not really use that, i can't see where a recursion is caused since i just said to mvc to create it for a model where all the fields are made with the 
"public 'type' 'name' { get; set;}" format. I will include the model, action, and view below.
This isn't really a problem for me since i do not use the templates at all but I am curious how this could happen when no custom code was inserted

Thanks in advance

Controller Action

```
public ActionResult View()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Model

```
namespace Data_Access.Models
{
    public class StudentModel
    {
        public int studentId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public string classroom { get; set; }
        public string role { get; set; }
        public string imgPath { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And finally the View

```
@model Data_Access.Models.StudentModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
}

<h2>View</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>StudentModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.studentId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.studentId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.studentId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.surname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.surname, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.surname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.classroom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.classroom, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.classroom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.role, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.role, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.role, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.imgPath, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.imgPath, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.imgPath, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The controller has infinite recursion:

```
public ActionResult View()
{
    return View();
}
```

Your View() method calls the same View() method ;)
Probably naming problem - I can't suggest any solution here, because you didn't take any information about the flow, what should be implemented in controller.

Comment: Good answer. I think the only sensible solution is to avoid naming conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

You can change action name to `ViewPage()` and add route attribute `Route[("View")]` above the action.

example:

```
[Route("View")]
public IActionResult ViewPage()
{
    return View();
}
```

then rename `View.cshtml` to `ViewPage.cshtml`

This will prevent recursive and you also use url path `/View`

I hope this will help you.